# hover event has no response using pure render in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, less

Instead of using state, I try to use css and pure render to make a hide and show effect.

```
.hover {
  position: relative;
}
.hover:hover .hover__no-hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hover:hover .hover__hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.hover__hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.hover__no-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

But somehow the hover event did not trigger?

```
export const Hover = ({ onHover, children }) => (
  <div className="hover">
    <div className="hover__no-hover">{children}</div>
    <div className="hover__hover">{onHover}</div>
  </div>
)

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hover onHover={<div> Show this on hover </div>}>
      <div> Show on no hover </div>
    </Hover>
  </div>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/6mk7p6l93 updated

Comment: You only mention CSS, but CSS does not support nested selectors. Are you actually using LESS as you've tagged?

Comment: Even the sandbox does not support LESS so it won't work no matter what.

Comment: @casieber complied to css but doesn't have any effect too.